# React Native line-through not centered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The strike through is not vertically centered.

My code is like this:

```
<Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through', alignSelf: 'center', fontFamily: constants.FONTBOLD, color: constants.ORANGE, fontSize: 16}}>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the font name? The font could be the culrprit.. some can be weird that way.

Comment: it's "Nunito", https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito?preview.text_type=custom

Comment: Can you look in your dev tools to see exactly what styling is being applied because in plain JavaScript/CSS the strike through is centred OK with font Nunito bold.

Comment: devtools inspector shows {textDecorationLine: line-through, fontFamiy: Nunito-Bold, color: #ff7009, fontSize: 16}

Answer (score 0):

well, we couldn't actually find a solution with the `textDecoration` property. But we did a work-around by placing absolutely a View. Like this (pseudo code)

````
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent: {
   position: relative, 
  },
  halfLine: {
    width: "100%",
    top: 0,
    height: "35%",
    borderBottomColor: "black",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    position: "absolute",
  },


<View class={styles.parent}>
 <View class={styles.halfLine} />
 <Copy> $100 </Copy>
</View>```
````